Suggestion: rename [tag:solo] to [tag:solo-mining]
I think that solo should be renamed to solo-mining because that is more self-explanatory. Afaik there are no other things that are related to solo with bitcoin, so it is not because of that (google bitcoin solo and the only thing that pops up except solo mining is the Hashlet Solo) but it improves the readability a lot in my opinion. 
When it is approved, I have no aversion to edit all 48 (at the moment) question myself, so no-one else should have any workload. 
PS. I'm not sure if this is a good Meta question. I could also have asked it in chat or answer/comment in the "Weeding out bad tags initiative 2014" but this gets probably more attention. 

Seems like a good suggestion. I agree that you should've asked it as a comment in bad tags initiative or in the chat room.

This is a very good suggestion, and exactly what meta is for. 
I think you are right, and I would suggest that we merge solo into solo-mining, which users can suggest and mods can do by themselves. That way, it is only a few clicks and  we don't have to manually edit questions whatsoever. :)

Actually, since I think it is very straightforward, I just enacted it immediately.
